# Add additional information to a HTML table cell without using inline CSS and no Javascript

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a HTML table where hovering over a cell adds additional information. The problem is that the site I am working on does not allow `<script>` or `<style>` tags for security reasons (?) so I am extremely limited in that regard.

```html
<table style="height: 100px; width: 50%; text-align: center;" bgcolor="blue">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;" colspan="1">First</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;" colspan="1">Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;" colspan="1">Third</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;" colspan="1">Fourth</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've seen tons of other threads when googling this issue, some people said to insert `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`but that's been disabled on the site too.

Ideally I wish I could do something like:

```
<td style="width: 50%; p:hover:after{content: 'Hidden Info'};" colspan="1">
<p>First</p>
</td>
```

But evidently that isn't allowed. So is there a way to insert text when the cell is hovered over without using Javascript or `<style>` tag? And if not what should I do to get the desired effect?

Comment: Why do you have styling for `p` on the `td` tag?

Comment: @Waxi I don't know I just thought it was appropriate (I am used OOP languages) html and such are alien to me

Comment: can you reference an external stylesheet  or is <link> prohibited?

Comment: You can't put the `:hover` inline, so if you don't have access to the stylesheet then it can't be done.

Comment: @brad nope the `<link>` tag is blocked as well

Comment: @waxi that's what I thought so is there a different way to achieve a similar affect?